# Magento Aheadwork Colorswatch not saving attribute images > 500?

Tags: php, magento

If you have a store that has potentially more than 190+ swatches to upload you.
Then it doesn't save them.

Comment: What is "Aw Colorswatch"? (Incidentally, whilst self-answered questions are fine, it is best to formulate the question _as_ if you didn't know the answer, so that other people can understand it too).

Comment: I'm guessing it's "aheadWorks Product Color Swatches", as seen [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-solor-swatches-by-aheadworks.html) and [here](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/product-color-swatches.html).

Comment: Yes it is about the magento colorswatch extension by Aheadwork. Please remove your down-votes. It can help to resolve the issue for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Set this setting in php.ini and it will work fine.

```
max_input_vars = 5000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000
```